# Java Springboot application is not increasing ID when writing in Oracle database instead I get an error

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, h2, liquibase

I have a java springboot application in which I am creating a table with liquibase in which I want to write an object history. However the id of the object is not increasing, instead I get an error that the database cannot write an object to the database when the id is null.

My object I want to write in the database looks like this:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "history")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class History{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true)
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

My liquibase changelog looks like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog'
        xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd'>

    <changeSet id='01-create table history' author='M. K.'>
        <createTable tableName='history'
                     remarks='A table to contain all history.'>
            <column autoIncrement='true' name='ID'
                    type='INTEGER'>
                <constraints nullable='false' primaryKey='true' primaryKeyName='HISTORYKEY'/>
            </column>
            <column name='NAME' type='varchar(100)'>
                <constraints nullable='true'/>
            </column>
...

        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Has anybody ideas on this?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To auto generate `id` you need to change `@GeneratedValue` and add `@SequenceGenerator` annotations in `History` class.
In `ChangeLog` before creating new table create sequence.

---

1. Add required annotations

```java
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_history", sequenceName = "seq_history_id", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_history")
@Column(unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private long id;
```

2. Add tag in change log to create sequence. Optional you can remove some unnecessary tag parameters:

```xml
<changeSet id='1' author='M. K.'>

    <createSequence incrementBy="1" sequenceName="seq_history_id" startValue="1"/>

    <createTable tableName='history'>
        <column name='id' type='bigint'>
            <constraints primaryKey='true' primaryKeyName='pk_history'/>
        </column>
...

    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

This is the way how I work with auto increment. I can ensure it works.

---

Additional info about liquibase change logs:

- If you use oracle you don't need to write names in upper case, because it might not work if you going to change database type (not oracle). Oracle automatically converts i.e. column names to upper case.
- You can remove `nullable="false"` if column is primary key. Because primary key is already not nullable and unique.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution.
It seems that Oracle needs a sequence to increase the id of an object.
My history object looks now like this:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "history")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class History {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HISTORYSEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "HISTORYSEQ", sequenceName = "HISTORYSEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true)
    private String name;
...
}
```

And my liquibase changelog looks like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog'
        xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd'>

    <changeSet id='01-create table history' author='M. K.'>

                <createSequence  startValue="1" incrementBy="1" ordered="true" sequenceName="HISTORYSEQ" maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="1" cacheSize="2"/>       

        <createTable tableName='history'
                     remarks='A table to contain all history.'>
            <column name='ID' type='INTEGER'>
                <constraints nullable='false' primaryKey='true'/>
            </column>
            <column name='NAME' type='varchar(100)'>
                <constraints nullable='true'/>
            </column>
...

        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Attention: The cache size has to be 2 or bigger.

I tested my changelog with h2 database, but this error was not found.

Anyway, I hope this helps anybody :)